# Prevención con INSERT: Warning: mysqli_query(): Empty query - PHP MySQL

Tags: php, mysqli, insert

Tengo una tabla en la cual necesito realizar dos INSERT simultáneos, sin embargo me da el siguiente  Warning: mysqli_query(): Empty query in C:\wamp64\www\SysCPC\action\adddocument.php on line 233 y solo me realiza uno ($query_2)

Otra caso a valorar es que realmente no me da un error al intentar hacer el INSERT del $query_1 (el grande) que es el que no esta realizando.

Y parece que todo lo toma como un STRING: este es el contenido del var_dump($query_1)

C:\wamp64\www\SysCPC\action\adddocument.php:110:string 'INSERT INTO document (consecutive, file_id, title, description, sheets, filecase_id, sender_id, kind_id, project_id, category_id, assigned_to, priority_id,
status_id, attach_id, way_id, craft, datecraft, user_received, received, user_create, created_at, session, date_session,
checked_craft, checked_session) VALUE ("2021-00002", "1", "Prueba 1", "Prueba 1", "1", "2", "3", "7", "3", "7", "31", "2",
'... (length=702)

Mi código es el siguiente:

```html
<?php
session_start();

    include "../config/config.php"; //Contiene funcion que conecta a la base de datos

    $received = $_POST['received'];
    $user_received = $_POST['user_received'];
    $filecase_id = $_POST['filecase_id'];
    $sheets = $_POST['sheets'];
    $sender_id = $_POST['sender_id'];
    $title = $_POST['title'];
    $kind_id = $_POST['kind_id'];
    $way_id = $_POST['way_id'];
    $description = $_POST['description'];
    $category_id = $_POST['category_id'];
    $priority_id = $_POST['priority_id'];
    $status_id = $_POST['status_id'];
    $attach_id = $_POST['attach_id'];
    $created_at = date("Y-m-d H:i:s");
    $user_create = $_SESSION['user_id'];
    $craft = $_POST['craft'];
    $datecraft = $_POST['craftdatetimepicker'];
    $file = empty($_POST['file']) ? "" : $_POST['file'];
    $session = empty($_POST['session']) ? "" : $_POST['session'];
    $date_session = date($_POST['date_sessiondatetimepicker']);

    if (isset($_POST['mostrar1']) == 1 && (isset($_POST['mostrar2']) == 1)) {

        $checked_craft = 1;
        $checked_session = 1;

        $query = mysqli_query($con, "SELECT COUNT(*) AS cont FROM consecutive WHERE year(created_at)=year(now())");

        if ($row = mysqli_fetch_array($query)) {
            $cont = $row['cont'] + 1; // incrementa   
            $num = sprintf("%'.05d", $cont); // formato con 5 digitos
            $codigo = date("Y") . "-" . $num; // se concatena con el año actual
        }

        $codigo1 = mysqli_query($con, "SELECT * FROM file WHERE file = $file");

        if ($f = mysqli_fetch_array($codigo1)) {
            $files = $f['id'];
        }

        if (isset($_POST["user_id"])) {
            $assigned_to = '';
            foreach ($_POST["user_id"] as $row) {
                $assigned_to .= $row . ', ';
            }
            $assigned_to = substr($assigned_to, 0, -2);
        }

        if (isset($_POST["project_id"])) {
            $project = '';
            foreach ($_POST["project_id"] as $row) {
                $project .= $row . ', ';
            }
            $project = substr($project, 0, -2);
        }

        $query_1 = "INSERT INTO document (consecutive, file_id, title, description, sheets, filecase_id, sender_id, kind_id, project_id, category_id, assigned_to, priority_id, 
                                       status_id, attach_id, way_id, craft, datecraft, user_received, received, user_create, created_at, session, date_session, 
                                       checked_craft, checked_session) VALUE (\"$codigo\", \"$files\", \"$title\", \"$description\", \"$sheets\", \"$filecase_id\", \"$sender_id\", \"$kind_id\", \"$project\", \"$category_id\", \"$assigned_to\", \"$priority_id\",
                                        \"$status_id\", \"$attach_id\", \"$way_id\", \"$craft\", \"$datecraft\", \"$user_received\", \"$received\", \"$user_create\", \"$created_at\", \"$session\", \"$date_session\",
                                        \"$checked_craft\", \"$checked_session\")";

        $query_2 = "INSERT INTO consecutive (consecutive, file_id) value (\"$codigo\",\"$files\")";
        $sql = mysqli_query($con, $query_1);
        $sql = mysqli_query($con, $query_2);
        
        }

    $query_new_insert = mysqli_query($con, $sql);

    if (!$query_new_insert) {
        $messages[] = "El Documento ha sido ingresado satisfactoriamente.";
    } else {
        $errors [] = "Lo siento algo ha salido mal intenta nuevamente." . mysqli_error($con);
    }
} else {
    $errors [] = "Error desconocido.";
}

if (isset($errors)) {
    ?>
  <div class="alert alert-danger" role="alert">
    <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="alert">&times;</button>
    <strong>Error!</strong>
    <?php
        foreach ($errors as $error) {
            echo $error;
        }
        ?>
  </div>
  <?php
}
if (isset($messages)) {
    ?>
    <div class="alert alert-success" role="alert">
      <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="alert">&times;</button>
      <strong>¡Bien hecho!</strong>
      <?php
        foreach ($messages as $message) {
            echo $message;
        }
        ?>
    </div>
    <?php
}
?>
```

Comment: No es una consulta, la variable esta recibiendo los dos insert

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Pueden ser varias razones.

- Primero ese segundo `insert` trata de imprimirlo y comprueba que es lo que intenta hacer y ejecútalo en *MySQL*, puede que te diga el error exacto.
- Uno de los errores más comunes es por la cantidad de caracteres que tienen permitidos lo campos, puede que los excedas o bien, que el tipo de dato sea incorrecto.

Comment: Efectivamente fue un campo que venia NULL

Answer (score 0):

Cuando dices:

> Y parece que todo lo toma como un STRING: este es el contenido del var_dump($query_1)

No parece que sea una cadena, así es como funcionan las consultas a base de datos tipo SQL, creando una cadena con instrucciones que después serán ejecutadas por el motor de base de datos, en tu caso, cuando usas `mysqli_query()`.

Te recomiendo usar [consultas preparadas](https://www.php.net/manual/es/mysqli.prepare.php) para minimizar la posibilidad de errores y ataques por inyección SQL, aparte de evitar escapar todas esas comillas dobles.

Con tu código actual, si un campo tiene comillas (simples o dobles), podría generar un error en la consulta

```
    $query_1 = "INSERT INTO document (consecutive, file_id, title, description, sheets, filecase_id, sender_id, kind_id, project_id, category_id, assigned_to, priority_id, 
                                   status_id, attach_id, way_id, craft, datecraft, user_received, received, user_create, created_at, session, date_session, 
                                   checked_craft, checked_session) VALUE (\"$codigo\", \"$files\", \"$title\", \"$description\", \"$sheets\", \"$filecase_id\", \"$sender_id\", \"$kind_id\", \"$project\", \"$category_id\", \"$assigned_to\", \"$priority_id\",
                                    \"$status_id\", \"$attach_id\", \"$way_id\", \"$craft\", \"$datecraft\", \"$user_received\", \"$received\", \"$user_create\", \"$created_at\", \"$session\", \"$date_session\",
                                    \"$checked_craft\", \"$checked_session\")";

    $query_2 = "INSERT INTO consecutive (consecutive, file_id) value (\"$codigo\",\"$files\")";
    $sql = mysqli_query($con, $query_1);
    // Revisa si se ejecutó correctamente, solo en etapa de desarrollo, nunca en producción
    if(!$sql)) {
        die('Hubo un error en la consulta: ' . mysqli_error($con));
    }
    $sql = mysqli_query($con, $query_2);
    if(!$sql)) {
        die('Hubo un error en la consulta: ' . mysqli_error($con));
    }
```

Más abajo tienes esta otra sentencia, donde `$sql` es un recurso de acceso a resultados de mysqli y, definitivamente, va a fallar, porque no es una cadena con una consulta adecuada:

```
$query_new_insert = mysqli_query($con, $sql);
```

**Por último**, la primera consulta `$query_1` falla porque tienes `VALUE` y debería ser `VALUES`. ¡Oh! Pasa también en la segunda consulta.